# Android: VideoView within Fragment only playing audio, not displaying video

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have a fragment that allows users to select from a mixed list of video and image content. When selecting a multimedia item, display is toggled between an `ImageView` and `VideoView` depending on the media type. The problem is, when the user selects a video, only the audio is played, and the `VideoView` remains black.

This is the code for displaying video: (Most of the code at the bottom is trial-and-error to see if something is missing to fix this issue)

```
mainVideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
mainImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
getActivity().getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
parent.showLoader(R.string.buffering);

mainVideo.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        parent.hideLoader();
        mainVideo.requestFocus();
        mainVideo.start();
    }
});
mainVideo.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        showErrorMessage(R.string.multimedia_load_failed, R.string.please_try_again_later);
        parent.hideLoader();
        return true;
    }
});
Uri video = Uri.parse(mm.url);
mainVideo.setMediaController(new MediaController(parent));
mainVideo.setKeepScreenOn(true);
mainVideo.bringToFront();
mainVideo.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
mainVideo.setActivated(true);
mainVideo.setEnabled(true);
mainVideo.setVideoURI(video);

Log.i(TAG, "Loading video: " + video.toString());
```

(`parent` is a reference to the activity that has some convenience functions like `showLoader` and whatnot.)

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout 
            android:layout_width="275dp"
            android:layout_height="275dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:background="@color/light_grey">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mm_main_image"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
            <RelativeLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <VideoView 
                    android:id="@+id/mm_main_video"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
                </VideoView>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mm_index_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/large_padding"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        <HorizontalScrollView 
            android:id="@+id/mm_horizontal_scroll"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout 
                android:id="@+id/mm_media_list"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content">
                <!-- Content filled dynamically -->
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I have looked all over StackOverflow and around the web for the last two days, but cannot find a solution to this problem anywhere. Any help is appreciated.

All of the videos (and images for that matter) are remote, they are not on the Android device.

Comment: This seems nearly identical to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13864118/android-videoview-control-is-not-displaying-video-only-audio-is-played but alas there is no good answer there either

Answer (score 5):

Try to remove any background color defined in the xml. It might cover the video view.

Comment: This fixed my problem. What a weird "feature." Thanks.

Comment: Apparently some confusion on the meaning of the word "background". *sigh*